# How to return lambda pointer in a template?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++11, lambda

I have to create a template whose return-value is a pointer to some lambda function (which is determined by template parameters).

The compiler feedback:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘laptr(int)’
```

What's wrong with the code? How to solve the problem?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T laptr(int par);

int main(){
    laptr(1);
    return 0;
}

///////////

template <typename T>
T laptr(int par)
{
    if (par == 1)
    {
        int p1 = [](int a, int b)->int{return a*b; };
        return p1;
    }
    else
    {
        double p2 = [](double a, double b)->double{return a + b; };
        return p2;
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler cannot infer the return type when calling your `laptr` method.

Comment: Template parameters of a function template are only deduced from its regular actual arguments, not from its body. Since `T` can never be deduced from the arguments that do not contain `T`, this template can only be called as `laptr<sometype>(value)`, which is obviously useless.

Comment: In addition, it looks like you are trying to return differently typed lambdas depending on the value of your parameter. Your syntax is incorrect but that's not important. This cannot be done at all. Templates do not magically make it possible.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `std::function` to store a lambda function:

```
template <typename T>
std::function<T(T,T)> laptr (int par)
{
    if(par == 1)
        return [](T a, T b)->T {return a*b;};
    else
        return [](T a, T b)->T {return a+b;};
}
```

or even a pointer to function

```
template <typename T>
auto laptr (int par) -> T(*)(T,T)
{
    ...
}
```

You can use it like this

```
auto func = laptr<double>(1);

auto result = func(8,2); // 8*2=16
```

Comment: Or even a plain old function pointer, if the lambdas don't need to capture anything.

Answer (score 3):

Your fundamental problem is that:

```
template <typename T>
```

...here, `T` is/must be determined entirely at *compile* time, but:

```
T laptr(int par)
```

`par` isn't known until run time, and:

```
if (par == 1)
{
    int p1 = [](int a, int b)->int{return a*b; };
    return p1;
}
else
{
    double p2 = [](double a, double b)->double{return a + b; };
    return p2;
}
```

Here, `T` isn't known until you've decided which leg of the `if` statement to execute, so the type 1) must be known before the code finishes compiling, not to mention anything about executing, but 2) can't be determined until the code executes.

Obviously you can't have both of those happen, so the code can't compile.

There are quite a few alternatives -- a pointer to a function, a `std::function`, a `Command` object (as defined in *Modern C++ Design*), etc. All of them will do the job essentially similarly: rather that attempting to return the precise type of each lambda, they're going to define some common type that can hold the type of either lambda, and return an object of that type instead.